# User Defined Function gives #VALUE!, but hand calculation works?

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a VBA user-defined function to calculate some thermal properties. The functions within this user-defined function reference a very large module which references a .DLL file (REFPROP in case you are curious).

When I plug everything into my function I get `#VALUE!`. However, if I do all the same steps as the function in my worksheet, I don't have any problems, I get a value. When I try to set up breaking points in my function, it will not stop at `FluidDensity`. Everything before that point stops and calculates correctly.

```
Option Explicit
Units = "E"
grav = 32.2

    Function DischargePipingLoss_per_FT(FluidName As String, BTUperHR As Double, OutsideDia_copper As String,LiquidTemp As Double, SuctionTemp As Double, Superheat As Double, PipeLossUnits As String, Isentropic_Eff As Double)

            Dim ps As Double
            Dim ts As Double
            Dim hs As Double
            Dim ss As Double
            Dim pd As Double
            Dim hd As Double
            Dim hd_actual As Double
            Dim td As Double
            Dim Re As Double, friction As Double
            Dim DynamicVisc As Double
            Dim KinematicViscosity_FT2perSEC As Double
            Dim InsideDia_FT As Double, PressureDrop_ft As Double
            Dim Velocity_FPS
            Dim BTUperLB As Double
            Dim LBperHR As Double
            Dim FT3perHR As Double
            Dim FluidDensity As Double
            Dim SuctionPressure As Double
            Dim ReturnGasTemp As Double
            Dim PSID_per_FT As Double

            'Determine suction pressure and temp
                ps = Pressure(FluidName, "Tvap", Units, SuctionTemp)
                ts = SuctionTemp + Superheat

            'Determine liquid enthalpy, suction gas enthalpy
                'hf = Enthalpy(FluidName, "PT", Units, HighPressure, GasCoolerOutletTemp)
                hs = VaporEnthalpy(FluidName, "PT", Units, ps, ts)

            'Determine return gas / discharge gas entropy
                ss = VaporEntropy(FluidName, "PT", Units, ps, ts)

            'Determine discharge pressure
                pd = Pressure(FluidName, "Tvap", Units, LiquidTemp)

            'Determine isentropic discharge gas enthalpy
                hd = Enthalpy(FluidName, "PS", Units, pd, ss)

            'Determine actual discharge gas enthalpy
                hd_actual = (hd - hs) / Isentropic_Eff + hs

            'Determine discharge temperature (uncomment if wanted)
                td = Temperature(FluidName, "PH", Units, pd, hd_actual)

            'calculate mass flowrate
                BTUperLB = RefrigerationEffect(FluidName, Units, LiquidTemp, SuctionTemp, Superheat)
                LBperHR = BTUperHR / BTUperLB

            'calculate fluid transport properties
                FluidDensity = Density(FluidName, "PH", Units, pd, hd_actual)
                DynamicVisc = Viscosity(FluidName, "PH", Units, pd, hd_actual)

           'calculate volume flowrate and velocity
                FT3perHR = LBperHR / FluidDensity
                InsideDia_FT = get_dia(OutsideDia_copper) / 12
                Velocity_FPS = FT3perHR / (3.14 * (InsideDia_FT / 2) ^ 2) / 3600

            'retrieve friction factor and calculate pressure drop (ft per ft)

                KinematicViscosity_FT2perSEC = DynamicVisc / FluidDensity
                PressureDrop_ft = FrictionFactor(Velocity_FPS, InsideDia_FT, KinematicViscosity_FT2perSEC) * (1 / InsideDia_FT) * (Velocity_FPS ^ 2 / (2 * grav))

            'convert pressure drop to psi per ft
            PSID_per_FT = PressureDrop_ft * FluidDensity / 12 ^ 2

            If PipeLossUnits = "PSI" Then
                DischargePipingLoss_per_FT = PSID_per_FT
            ElseIf PipeLossUnits = "degF" Then
                DischargePipingLoss_per_FT = deltaT(FluidName, td, PSID_per_FT)
            Else: DischargePipingLoss_per_FT = "error"
            End If

        End Function
```

Comment: `Units` is not a declared variable in `ps = Pressure(FluidName, "Tvap", Units, SuctionTemp)` make sure you use `Option Explicit`. What you can do to debug the function is writing a test sub that is calling the function like `Debug.Print DischargePipingLoss_per_FT("nnn", 2, "copper", 10, 11, 12, "unit", 2)` then start the test sub with F8 and go through step by step.

Comment: The function is invoking other functions - do any of these have any kind of side-effects on global or workbook/worksheet state? A UDF isn't allowed to alter any cells, in any way. What's the `Density` function doing?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ forgot to include my global scope declarations, so units is defined

Comment: @Mat'sMug The density function is calling a separate function in another module. I know this is not a problem, because I have many other functions doing the same thing without issue.

Comment: Ok. *Something, somewhere*, is being invoked and doing something it shouldn't be doing. You can very well invoke a UDF from VBA code without any errors and get the expected result - and then you get `#VALUE` when you try to use that same UDF from a worksheet cell. The problem is that we're not seeing such code here, so the answer below is likely the best you'll be getting.

Comment: Figured it out. Used the Immediate Window and was able to see the error messages being sent from the DLL and fixed my formulas. Nothing wrong with how it was coded. Seems to be an issue with the DLL I'm using and one particular equation. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

`#VALUE` is the standard answer of the Excel VBA, when a UDF function is trying to change the environment of Microsoft Excel (see the yellow square).

Check this small function:

```
Public Function Example() As Long
    'Range("A1") = 10
    Example = 5
End Function
```

If you call it like this `=Example` in Excel, it will return 5.

Then, if you uncomment the `Range("A1")=10` you will see that the `#VALUE` error appears. Thus, long story short - your function (or the one it is calling) is obviously doing something illegal. Try to find what is it and eliminate it.

---

> A user-defined function called by a formula in a worksheet cell cannot change the environment of Microsoft Excel. This means that such a function cannot do any of the following:
>
> - Insert, delete, or format cells on the spreadsheet.
> - Change another cell's value.
> - Move, rename, delete, or add sheets to a workbook.
> - Change any of the environment options, such as calculation mode or screen views.
> - Add names to a workbook.
> - Set properties or execute most methods.

[support.microsoft.com - Description of limitations of custom functions in Excel](http://Description%20of%20limitations%20of%20custom%20functions%20in%20Excel)